line spacing is more because of font
I am using Changa font in one of my app. The issue in the font what I am using have extra white space at top & bottom.
I am simply setting text & font to the UILabel as below.
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Changa-Regular", size: 14)!
myLabel.text = "Lorem ipsum"

If you see below screenshot (second yellow label) you will notice that space between 2 fonts is very big.
Also for test I give background color to first label (first yellow). If you see font is having white space at top and bottom too.
Any idea how can we remove or decrease that white spacing that is there default in the font?


See this. The accepted answer there basically works on a UILabel, even though it is for SwiftUI.

@Sweeper : I see it is using AttributedString->lineSpacing. I know using this but I don't feel it's proper way. Is there any direct way?

What do you mean by a "direct" way?

@Sweeper : Any other alternate way?

No, there is no interline spacing options in UILabel, you need to do it yourself with NSAttributedString, that or modify Changa to change the interline parameters.

modify Changa font I feel is the ideal solution...

I found an extension which helped to fix the issue.
public func zeroLineSpace(){
    let s = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    let lineHeight = self.font.pointSize - self.font.ascender + self.font.capHeight + 10
    let offset = self.font.capHeight - self.font.ascender + 5
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.text!.count)
    style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
    style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
    style.alignment = self.textAlignment
    s.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
    s.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: offset, range: range)
    self.attributedText = s
    self.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
}

